# Cocos2D - filling a sprite

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

UIImageViews have a property called contentMode that you can use as

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

and it will fill the entire view with your image without distorting, even if it has to bleed the image to do that.

Is there any similar stuff on Cocos2D? Sorry about the question, but I am new to Cocos2d.

I am creating the sprite like this:

```
CCTexture2D *textBack = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:image];
CCSprite *sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithTexture:textBack];
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent method to performing a UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit would be the **.scale** property. When a CCNode (or any of the sub nodes such as CCSprite etc.) is first created, the scale property is 1. Keep increasing it to scale the sprite up proportionally.

```
sprite.scale = 2.0f; // Scales the sprite proportionally at a factor of 2
```

As for it fitting to a specific size, you would have to write a routine:

1. Pass in desired rect and CCSprite bounding box rect.
2. Scale the box rect to aspect fit the desired rect.
3. Return the scaling factor

The result can then be applied to the CCSprite.scale property.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly scale the sprite to do that...

```
sprite.scale  = ?
sprite.scaleX = ?
sprite.scaleY = ?
```

but I don't believe there is a function to automatically fill the entire screen.  If you don't get a definitive reply here I would suggest posting on the Cocos2D forums (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/).